# How do I remove (not hide) the space between the web part zone and title

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

The link [here](http://www.ashokraja.me/tips/How-To-Remove-Extra-Space-Around-the-Web-Part-In-SharePoint-2013) explains how to remove the space btw WebParts.  This is great, but how do I remove space between the web part zone and the title

Comment: did you try one of the solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css property,

```
display:none;
```

and make the adjustment of the second webpart using :

```
margin-top:(as per adjustment) px;   eg: `margin-top:20px;`
```

Comment: can you specify to which css class it applies ?

Comment: Apply the property to corresponding class eg : .ms-WPBody or to the ID #WebPartWPQ6

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you are looking for..

The following code will remove some white space over the title:

```
.ms-webpart-titleText
{
    line-height:1;
}
```

you can also remove another pixel by the following:

```
.s4-wpcell > .ms-webpart-chrome, .s4-wpactive > .ms-webpart-chrome
{
    border-top-width:0px;
}
```